SQL Server cannot create assembly as it references system.runtime, version=5.0.0.0
I'm trying to create my first CLR assembly. I have created a dll in VS and now I am trying to use it in SQL Server.
I try to create assembly with this code:
CREATE ASSEMBLY SQLCLRroy
FROM '...\SqlExternalFunctions\bin\Debug\net5.0\SQLExternalFunctions.dll';

but I get an error

Assembly 'SqlExternalFunctions' references assembly 'system.runtime, version=5.0.0.0, culture=neutral, publickeytoken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a.', which is not present in the current database.

After trawling the net I try this:
CREATE ASSEMBLY [System.Runtime] 
FROM 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref\5.0.0\ref\net5.0\System.Runtime.dll'

which again results in an error

Warning: The Microsoft .NET Framework assembly 'system.runtime, version=5.0.0.0, culture=neutral, publickeytoken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a.' you are registering is not fully tested in the SQL Server hosted environment and is not supported.

Do I need to stop my .NET code from referencing System.Runtime somehow? The only package I have is System.Data.SqlClient
My .NET code is very simple:
using System;
using System.Linq;

public static class SqlExternalFunctions
{
    [Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.SqlFunction]
    public static int myTest(int param )
    {
        return param;
    }
}


.net core is probably too heavyweight to use for CLR, you should keep it to the list of the mentioned assemblies: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/sql/database-engine/general/policy-untested-net-framework-assemblies

See also: Common language runtime (CLR) integration programming concepts which includes, SQL Server CLR integration doesn't support .NET Core, or .NET 5 and later versions.

thanks @siggemannen you gave me the clue. I was using .Net Core instead of .Net Framework when I built my class in VS

Use .Net Framework not .Net Core as the Target Framework in VS
